# pygame wont load images

Tags: python, image, load, pygame

```
bck = "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\back.jpg"
mse = "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mouse.jpg"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()


screen=pygame.display.set_mode((600,344),0,32)

background=pygame.image.load(bck).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mse).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

I get this error when using a double slash program, but the images don't show:

> File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\game.py", line 12, in 
>      background=pygame.image.load(bck).convert()
>   error: Couldn't open C:\Python27\Lib\site-packagesack.jpg

It doesn't seem to be able to find the images

When I use the double slash or forwards slash it runs fine but doesn't display images.
I've tried it in multiple directories and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use `/` instead of `\` in paths, if you write `print(bck)` it will output this:

```
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\x08ack.jpg'
```

This is because `'\b'` is decoded to `'\x08'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bck = r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\back.jpg"
mse = r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mouse.jpg"
```

use r or double slashes when putting in a path so that it is recognized as a raw string.